# How do I make the light go behind the Earth?

Tags: light, compositing-nodes

[image: This is the image.]

Additional info:

I'm working in the compositing section, and only there it looks like that. If i turn on rendered mode, it will look like this [image: this]

If you need any more info please ask me!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! What exactly is your issue? Is it that the background disappears when switching to the rendered view? It could also be helpful to provide the .blend file, e.g. using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello! I was not very detailed, I want the light emitted by the white sphere to go behind the Earth. The background is not the problem (i turned on transparent in the render properties). My target is to look like something similar to this:  https://imgur.com/a/rpCOxiy. There the light doesn't cover the Earth so much. Also, here is the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Eo5b5KwJ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Eo5b5KwJ/)

Comment: It appears to me that you refer to the lens flare. Have you edited one in post? If so, try to play around a bit with the settings and see what changes

Answer (score 0):

The lens flare you refer to as "Light" should according to normal physics never be blocked by an obstacle. If you still want this effect tho, you should try to mask out the earth in your post processing. To do this, create a second layer in which you render your earth completely white with your background completely black. Do this, with either the emission shader or an background shader. You also need to render a layer without lens flare. Then you can use your mask and to overlay the flare less render above the one with flare using an alpha over node.

Comment: Side note, if you add the lens flare in your post processing you can simply crop the flare with your mask, instead of overlaying another render.